# Where can I find the .crt and .key files on my Plesk server

Tags: laravel, plesk

I'm running a server with plesk, and trying to find the .key and .crt files that are generated by letsencrypt.

I'm running plesk on an Ubuntu server and have already tried the .pem files but my web-sockets wont accept those.

Does anybody know the location/file-path of these files?

paths for keys

```
/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
```

**websockets**

```
        /*
         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
         */
        'local_cert' => env('LOCAL_CERT'),
        //'local_cert' => null,

        /*
         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
         */
        'local_pk' => env('LOCAL_PK'),
        //'local_cert' => null,

        /*
         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
         */
        'passphrase' => env('PASSPHRASE', null),
        'verify_peer' => false,

    ],
```

**Broadcasting**

```
        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'eu',
                'host' => env('PUSHER_APP_HOST'),
                'port' => env('PUSHER_APP_PORT'),
                'scheme' => 'https',
                //'useTLS' => true,
                //'encrypted' => true,
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],

        ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LetsEncrypt will use .pem on ubuntu. The file extension shouldn't matter though, so if you are encountering an error when trying to use the pem files files then you should share and investigate the error message.

Comment: The connection keeps timing out. It runs locally with valet en directing the path to the right paths, but the same code on my server doesn't